# Turn XML attribute with 2 or more values into SVG x/y coordinates using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, svg

I need to turn the values in a xml attribute through xsl into a svg rect pos x and y

Therefore need to parse from

Examples

```
<item value="20 10 40" />
<item value="200 0 100" />
<item value="2666 10 40 95" />
```

parse each item value attribute following some rules (that's the part I'm not sure about, how to extract the numbers into separate variables)

like

```
 <item value="20 10 40" />
              X  Z  Y
```

Extract X (20) in var1 and Y (40) in var2

into

```
<rect x="{$var1}" y="{$var2}" />
```

(if I want the first and third value in this case)

Basically I need to understand how to parse any TWO of a series of multiple values contained within the attribute VALUE and pass them into the rect vars as var1 and var2 separately.

From my research so far, I have found out 2 methods but not sure how to apply in this case, either substring-before and after or tokenize, please note this needs to work loaded directly in a browser.

**Edit1**

I have found an ugly solution so far to extract the data for a case of 3 numbers

Xml

```
<item value="20 10 40" />
```

Xsl

```
Value 1    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before (@value, ' ')"/>
Value 2    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after (@value, ' '), ' ')"/>
Value 3    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after (@value, ' '), ' ')"/>
```

Result

```
Value 1    20
Value 2    10
Value 3    40
```

So looking for something cleaner, perhaps recursive that accept any amount of numbers in the string and parse all.

Comment: Are you saying you want to map from 3 `items` to 1 `rect`?  1 `item` to 1 `rect`?   How exactly?  You've not explained what you want to do clearly enough for us to help.

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for a flexible solution so I can parse any two numbers of my choice within value attribute separated by a space (like first and third number from left to right) and through xsl put them into 2 separate x and y variables in rect.

Comment: Please indicate if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Looking for a clean solution that works loading xml in a modern browser like chrome or firefox (and applies xsl stylesheet), so I suppose 1.0, as I have read browsers are not supporting 2.0

Comment: If you need to do this for lots of input data then my first suggestion would be to change XML format to put any single value in a single element. If you can't do that then look into http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html where the XSLT implementation is provided at http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/str.tokenize.template.xsl.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I cannot modify the xml format and I need to use xslt 1.0, tokenize, correct me if I'm wrong is xslt 2.0 and doesn't work when xml and xslt are simply loaded in a browser

Comment: The links I have pointed you to provide an XSLT 1.0 based implementation of a `tokenize` template.

Comment: It's not clear how I can use that, could you help with a working example using my xml sample, so I can connect the dots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting values from a delimited list in XSLT 1.0 is awkward, since it has no `tokenize()` function.

If the number of values in the list is small (like in your example), you can use nested `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` calls, as shown (now) in your question.

A more generic solution, which is also more suitable to handle larger lists, would use a recursive named template, for example:

```
<xsl:template name="get-Nth-value">
    <xsl:param name="list"/>
    <xsl:param name="N"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$N = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($list, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter) and $N > 1">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="get-Nth-value">
                <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-after($list, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="N" select="$N - 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Example of call:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
    <rect>
        <xsl:attribute name="x">
            <xsl:call-template name="get-Nth-value">
                <xsl:with-param name="list" select="@value"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="N" select="1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>                
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="y">
            <xsl:call-template name="get-Nth-value">
                <xsl:with-param name="list" select="@value"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="N" select="2"/>
            </xsl:call-template>                
        </xsl:attribute>
    </rect>
</xsl:template>
```

Demo:http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7mh

Comment: Thanks Michael, would you mind to amend the code to work with the XML  <item value="20 10 40" /> so it's clearer, and point out how I can target each value specifically If I want to render only  specific ones?

Comment: @Onetyper See the additions to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using the EXSLT extensions, online at http://xsltransform.net/bnnZW2, the code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl str">

    <xsl:include href="http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/str.tokenize.template.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="tokens-rtf">
            <xsl:call-template name="str:tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="@value"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="exsl:node-set($tokens-rtf)/token"/>
        <x>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[1]"/>
        </x> 
        <y>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[2]"/>
        </y>
      </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

the input is

```
<root>
    <item value="20 10 40" />
    <item value="200 0 100" />
    <item value="2666 10 40 95" />
</root>
```

the output is

```
<root>
    <item><x>20</x><y>10</y></item>
    <item><x>200</x><y>0</y></item>
    <item><x>2666</x><y>10</y></item>
</root>
```

It should be clear how to access other tokens by the position, of course you can also `for-each` or `apply-templates` over `$tokens`.

Note that XSLT processors in browsers might not allow you to import or include a stylesheet module from a different domain, so you would to make sure you put the referenced stylesheet module (`str.tokenize.template.xsl`) on your own server and reference it from there.