# How can I select individual attribute values in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML that looks like this:

```
<interp type="flowers color">Here is something concerning flowers and color.</interp>
```

And I'm trying to transform it into something like this:

```
<td class="interp">
    <span class="tag">flowers</span>
    <span class="tab">color</span>
    Here is something concerning flowers and color. 
</td>
```

So this is the XSL I've been trying:

```
<xsl:template match="interp">
    <td class="interp">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@type | node()"/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@type">
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
    <span class="tag">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </span>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

But what I get is more like this:

```
<span class="tag">flowers color</span>
Here is something concerning flowers and color.
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get these attribute values to separate?

Answer (score 0):

Using an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 you can use `<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\s+')">`. With XSLT 1.0 check whether your processor supports an extension function or use a template to split or tokenize the attribute value, see http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html.

Comment: I'm just using Firefox, and when I try using the tokenize function, it says "Error during XSLT transformation: An unknown XPath extension function was called."

Comment: Well, I said the `tokenize` approach works with an XSLT 2.0 processor, unfortunately browsers force you to use XSLT 1.0 from 1999. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838519/turn-xml-attribute-with-2-or-more-values-into-svg-x-y-coordinates-using-xsl/33843236#33843236 for an example on how to use a named template to tokenize an attribute value in XSLT 1.0.