# Substring-after ignore unknown

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

XML:

```
<param name="SomeName">
                      <path>'root.domain.sub1.sub2.sub3.subover9000'</path>
</param>
```

The `root.domain.` is a static value, `sub1.sub2.sub3.subover9000` is a dynamic value. Where I want to select the `sub2` value as output.

My XSLTv1:

```
<xsl:variable name="Sysid" select="//@name[normalize-space(.) = 'SomeName']/parent::*"/>    
<xsl:variable name="SSafter" select="substring-after( $Sysid, 'root.domain.')"/>
<xsl:variable name="SSbefore" select="substring-before( $SSafter, '.sub3.subover9000')"/>

<xsl:value-of select="$SSbefore"/>
```

Output:

```
sub1.sub2
```

The problem is - I cannot renounce `sub1.` because its dynamic in different XML files, but I only need `sub2`.

So how can I say to ignore part between `root.domain.` and next `dot"."`?

The rule says:

> The expression fn:substring-after("abcdefghi", "--d-e-",
>   "http://www.w3.org/2013/collation/UCA?lang=en;alternate=blanked;strength=primary")
>   returns "fghi".

Which in my view means, when I use:

```
<xsl:variable name="SSafter" select="substring-after( $Sysid, '--root.domain.-.-')"/>
```

I should get `sub2` as output, but I don't.

Comment: Are you really using a XSLT 3.0 processor?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I apologize in advance, that's what I'm using: `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors" exclude-result-prefixes="array fn map math xhtml xs err" version="3.0"></xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: That doesn't mean anything - I am asking about the XSLT **processor engine** you are using. Only yesterday you told us it was limited to XSLT 1.0. If you don't know, find out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033

Comment: @michael.hor257k You're right, I am wrong. It is vesion 1. Do I need to change it or is there a way to do what I mantioned with version 1?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 is Turing-complete, so there is a way, but it's awkward. Which specific engine is it?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Microsoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="string">root.domain.sub1.sub2.sub3.subover9000</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($string, 'root.domain.'), '.'), '.')"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>sub2</result>
```

---

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33841806/3016153 for a generic template to extract N-th token from a delimited string.

Comment: I am appreciated and thanks for provided informations it helps me alot,
and it works ofcourse.
I only changed `<xsl:param name="string" select="$Sysid"/>` to make it multi usable for different XML files.