# Get comma separated string into each row of CSV using XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, csv, xslt

I would like to make a xslt template that gets comma separated string into each row in CSV.

My current xslt is as below for reference.
I don't have any issue getting information from my Person class, but as for Item, i need to get from variable and the template for "Item" below is not correct. And I cannot use tokenize since my xslt version is 1.

Id, Name and Address can be getting it from Person class in C#.
ItemValue is a separate variable.
The number of person count and ItemValue count are tally. Even if the count are mismatched, ItemValue can be left as empty. As I cannot attached a new variable to exiting person class.

xml would probably look like this.

```
<PersonList>
  <Person>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Name1</Name>
    <Address>Add1</Address>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>Name2</Name>
    <Address>Add2</Address>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Name>Name3</Name>
    <Address>Add3</Address>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <Name>Name4</Name>
    <Address>Add4</Address>
  </Person>
<PersonList>
```

My expected csv and xml will look like as below.

[image]

```
   <PersonList>
      <Person>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>Name1</Name>
        <Address>Add1</Address>
        <ItemValue>item1</ItemValue>
      </Person>
      <Person>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Name>Name2</Name>
        <Address>Add2</Address>
        <ItemValue>item2</ItemValue>
      </Person>
      <Person>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <Name>Name3</Name>
        <Address>Add3</Address>
        <ItemValue>item3</ItemValue>
      </Person>
      <Person>
        <ID>4</ID>
        <Name>Name4</Name>
        <Address>Add4</Address>
        <ItemValue>item4</ItemValue>
      </Person>
    <PersonList>
```

Below is current xslt. I don't add any xml tag since my desired output is in csv format.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">   
            
            <xsl:param name="items">
                <xsl:text>item1,item2,item3,item4</xsl:text>
            </xsl:param>

            
            <xsl:template name="Header" match="/">
                <xsl:text>Id</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>Name</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>Address</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>ItemValue</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//Person" />
            </xsl:template>
            
            <xsl:template match="Person">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Id" />
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="@Name" />
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="@Address" />
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//Item">
                    <xsl:with-param name="Person" select="." />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:template>
            
            <xsl:template match="Item">
                <xsl:variable name="itemList" select="substring-before(concat($items, ','), ',')" />
                <xsl:for-each select="$itemList">
                   <item>
                       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                   </item>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add (1) an example of XML input and (2) the expected output.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33841806/3016153

Comment: not really. I want to iterate "items". Would like to put first item found separated by ',' in first row. 2nd item found in 2nd row, etc.

Comment: I still don't see what your input looks like. In any case, if you want to add the 1st item to the 1st row, the 2nd item to the 2nd row, and so on, then the linked answer is **exactly** what you're looking for.

Comment: if so, may i know how do i do that in xslt?

Comment: I still don't see what your input looks like. and I am getting tired of asking. It's also not clear what should happen when the number of items is not equal to the number of persons (?) in your XML.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.
All within the question, no images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could handle this is to adapt the solution I linked to in the comments as follows:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:param name="items">item1,item2,item3,item4</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/PersonList">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>Id,Name,Adress,ItemValue&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Person">
        <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>  
        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>  
        <xsl:value-of select="Address"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>  
        <xsl:call-template name="get-Nth-value">
            <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$items"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="N" select="position()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>  
        <!-- recursive call -->
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="get-Nth-value">
    <xsl:param name="list"/>
    <xsl:param name="N"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$N = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($list, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter) and $N > 1">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="get-Nth-value">
                <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-after($list, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="N" select="$N - 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your example input (corrected for well-formedness!), this will return:

**Result**

```
Id,Name,Adress,ItemValue
1,Name1,Add1,item1
2,Name2,Add2,item2
3,Name3,Add3,item3
4,Name4,Add4,item4
```

---

However, it might be better to reduce the number of required iterations by processing both the XML and the `$items` parameter in parallel:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:param name="items">item1,item2,item3,item4</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/PersonList">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>Id,Name,Adress,ItemValue&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
        <xsl:with-param name="persons" select="Person"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$items"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-rows">
    <xsl:param name="persons"/>
    <xsl:param name="items"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter">,</xsl:param>
    <xsl:if test="$persons">
        <xsl:variable name="person" select="$persons[1]" />
        <!-- write to output -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$person/ID"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>  
        <xsl:value-of select="$person/Name"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>  
        <xsl:value-of select="$person/Address"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>  
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($items, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>  
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="persons" select="$persons[position() > 1]"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="items" select="substring-after($items, $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this assumes that the `$items` parameter value is supplied at runtime. If it can be hard-coded, then the solution could be much simpler.

And we still don't know  what should happen when the number of items is not equal to the number of persons.

Comment: Thanks for solution, michael. I try using the first solution you provided. But i was wondering if any way that i can get position() without associating with person foreach loop. Coz my real use case have to treat person template and items template separately.

Comment: I am afraidI cannot help you with a situation I do not understand.